# Is Model.update a promise in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, promise, sails.js, waterline

I'm currently working on a Sails.js app, and in a model function, I need to execute some queries in order. I'm using the default promises in waterline, but it's not working with the following code:

```
Model.find().where({id: 1}).then(function(value){
    return Model.update({id: value[0].id}, {/**some value assignment here*/});
}).then(function(moreValues){
    //here the 'moreValues' is an empty array
    //more code here
});
```

The `update` function of the models returns a promise? If it does, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: `but it's not working`. What's not working? Post an error message, stack trace, something. Of course somrthing is "not working", that's why you're on Stack Overflow

Comment: what do you think `return Module.update(...)` does? Because what it won't do is give you the updated model. You won't have that unless you follow the pattern [given by the official documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/models/update.html)

Comment: I've not explained myself very well. What I want to know is why `Model.update` does not return the updated row. I've checked the values and they are correct. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans @TravisWebb

Comment: Problem solved. It was a bad variable assignment. Typical. Thank you all for the kind words.

Comment: hmm, but that's still going about it the wrong way then? Instead of continuing the promise chain after you *issue* the update (using that return), you actually want to continue it once the update callback is called, because otherwise you have no guarantee that the model was updated by the time you continue.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Do you have an example of how to properly continue the promise chain after the callback has finished. 

BTW: Do you know why the updated records are returned when using a Promise together with Model.update? Other model methods work as expected with Promises ...

Comment: @GerardoNavarroSuarez better to ask this as your own question with your own code and explanation than to ask about a question I left a comment on almost two years ago. You'll get more eyes on it that way, and probably a better response than I can give you based on just a comment.